# Protect RunCustomQuery(string SqlQuery, List<IDbDataParameter> SqlParameters) from injection

Tags: c#, sql-injection, code-analysis

We use a class, `DBLinker`, to connect to various databases and run queries.

It relies on its core method, `RunCustomQuery(string p_strSqlQuery, List<IDbDataParameter> p_lisParameters)` to return `Select` query results or execute `Insert`, `Update` or `Delete` queries (possibly returning the new row's ID in the first case).

It may bear noting that the queries can be run on various database systems, depending on `DBLinker` properties that I won't go into detail about.

Recently, all our projects have gone through an analysis by Kiuwan. Said analysis brings up a very high vulnerability through injection in `RunCustomQuery()`.

Here is the relevant code, snipped for brevity:

```cs
public virtual object RunCustomQuery(string p_strSqlQuery, out string p_strSqlActualQuery, List<IDbDataParameter> p_lisParameters = null)
{
    p_strSqlActualQuery = p_strSqlQuery;
    // [...]

    IDbCommand z_dcdCommand = null;
    IDbDataAdapter z_daaAdaptateur = null;
    try
    {
      // [...] create z_dcdCommand according to the target database system
      z_dcdCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      // [...]
      if (p_lisParameters != null)
      {
         foreach (IDbDataParameter z_dpaParameter in p_lisParameters) // Here Kiuwan says there's a data path sink
         {
            // [...]
            p_strSqlActualQuery =p_strSqlActualQuery.Replace(z_dpaParameter.ParameterName.ToString(),DBHelper.FormatForSql(z_dpaParameter, SGBD));            
            switch (SGBD)
            {
               case TypeSGBD.SqlServer:{  // RAS break; }
               case TypeSGBD.Oracle:
               case TypeSGBD.Sybase:
               {
                    // Caution: parameters must be declared in the same order in the query and in the list.
                    p_strSqlQuery = p_strSqlQuery.Replace(z_dpaParameter.ParameterName.ToString(), "?");
                    z_dpaParameter.ParameterName = "?";
                    break;
                }
             }
           z_dpaParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
           z_dcdCommand.Parameters.Add(z_dpaParameter);
          }
        }

           z_dcdCommand.CommandText = p_strSqlQuery; // Here Kiuwan says there's a propagation path sink
           // [...]
           // [...] Actually run the command, with ExecuteReader(), a IDbDataAdapter or ExecuteNonQuery() according to the query type
       }
       catch (Exception z_excException)
       {
          // [...] Management (transaction rollback, among others)
          throw;
       }
       finally
       {
          // [...] Tie up loose ends
          z_dcdCommand?.Dispose();
       }
 }
```

Obviously we want these injection risks gone, but I don't know what can be done about it here. Is it simply that nothing guarantees a "clean" query in `p_strSqlQuery`? I can't see how to salvage the method in that case.

Also, I don't get why Kiuwan singles out the `foreach (p_lisParameters)` row.

What should we do?

Answer (score 0):

By its design this is a dangerous sink.  This is, in effect, meant to cover the query functionality for different DBs.  It should be treated the same as the underlying JDBC functions by the tool.

It’s a little hard to tell from this code snippet, but it looks like it may not be using the parameterized query mechanisms for each of the databases.  If that’s the case it should do so.  That will ensure the parameters are correctly “sanitized“.

The SQL itself is going to be a dangerous sink (SQL injection endpoint).  This means that you need to ensure that only trusted sources are used for this parameter.  The same way you would ensure that any SQL statement in a database statement is trusted.

I’m not familiar with Kiuwan but most code analysis tools have a mechanism to mark a parameter in a function as a dangerous source. That will allow you to determine if any untrusted (tainted) inputs can be traced to this parameter.